# Restrict a particular page in Blue Spice Wiki

Tags: wiki

I am trying to restrict a certain page on my Blue Spice wiki to only be viewable by certain users or groups. Is there a way to do this? We are using the free version right now.

Thank you,

Comment: Your best place to ask is in a Blue Spice community - they know about the software https://sourceforge.net/projects/bluespice/support

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer:

https://en.wiki.bluespice.com/wiki/Manual:Extension/PageAccess

You add this anywhere in the source code of the page:

`<bs:pageaccess groups="secure1,secure2" />`

Where "secure1" and "secure2" are the names of groups that you want to have access to the page.